# mvn - spring boot JPA MVC cant resolve @Entity annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am learning Spring Boot following a course, the MVC part of the course tried to also teach JPA and trying to create a model the instructor showed the following code.

```
package com.user.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Persona {
}
```

the problem is the `@Entity` annotation which can not be resolved. I have the JPA Dependency in the pom.xml file like is seen here:

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tito</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoWebApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoWebApplication</name>
    <description>Demo for webapplication</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The IDE i am using is intelliJ IDEA and this is the warning showing:

[image: IDE Intellij IDEA Warning]

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Have you reimported the dependencies? Right click on Pom.xml -> maven -> reimport

Comment: i cant' belive this was the problem. Thanks you a lot, also there is no a reimport instead i clicked Reload Project and works.

Comment: There is a button “auto reload” somewhere in the maven settings, but I don’t remember where